# Pushpin Accuracy

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-7, bing-maps

I have a pushpin I place on a map. If i'm zoomed in very close, the pushpin is very accurate. I can see it lands basically on a house I want it to. As I zoom out, the pushpin moves a little, the more I zoom out, the less accurate it is. It should remain accurate at all zoom levels.

At street level it's accurate to within 10 feet or so.
At county zoom level, it's 2-3 miles off centered.
At state zoom level it's 100+ Miles off centered.
At country zoom level, it's 3 states off center.

I don't remember having this issue before, trying to track down a reason or setting I used to cause this.

Other strange thing, I have a circle that I draw on the map, and that poly is deadly accurate at any zoom.

I have a feeling it's because I add pins to a maplayer first. Although I don't know why this would matter. Is there some setting I need to add to the maplayer before I add it as a child to the map?

Pushpins get added to the maplayer, maplayer gets added to the map. Although, it seems the maplayer has issues with staying accurate at zoom levels.

Any thoughts as to why I would have accuracy issues at zoom levels with pins on a maplayer?

```
   var mapLayer = new MapLayer();
    var youPushpin = new Pushpin { 
        Height = 70,
        Width = 60,
        Background = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Transparent),
    };
    mapLayer.AddChild(youPushpin, new GeoCoordinate(Convert.ToDouble(_settings.Latitude), Convert.ToDouble(_settings.Longitude)), PositionOrigin.BottomCenter);
    ParkingMap.Children.Add(mapLayer);
```

Comment: Note, that the point to which `Pushpin` related, is places in left-bottom corner, so you may be confused with transparent background why your `Pushpin`-content is point to different locations

Comment: hrmm but why would it work fine when added directly to the map without a maplayer?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that it is off because of the way you are placing the Pushpin. Why are you adding the Pushpins like that anyways? Try just setting the Pushpin's Location property and then adding it to the map layer's children.

I would actually recommend not creating Pushpins in code at all. Look at my [answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6999225/interactive-layers-in-bing-map-control-for-silverlight-4-and-windows-phone-7). It shows how to quickly and easily use databinding to display Pushpins through xaml. Feel free to not use the ellipse control template.